# Remote recording in studios?

Tags: remote, monitoring, recording

Hi

Recently my boss asked gave me an Innkeeper4 and asked me to figure out a way to setup remote audio monitoring for Disney producers sitting in their office and directing the voice artist and engineer who are in a studio miles away, with a Protools 10 HD setup.

I was amazed by the capabilities of Innkeeper 4 and i was on the verge of pulling my hair out with frustration due to the complexity of the routing (and frustratingly the setup would work in 1 studio, but not in another main studio) so that the producers could here the artist on mic, engineer through talkback and also speak to the artist and engineer over the phone line, connected to Innkeeper and Protools 10 HD and also explaining the routings to another engineer who would be the actual recordist. Finally after a demo, the producers liked the voice quality they were hearing.

This led me to think, is it possible to record remotely as well? I recently saw a video of George Lucas sitting with his Supervising sound editor for Starwars, in a studio, watching a movie clip, which was running in sync with the same file being played in a studio in Australia, where the ADR was taking place...though they were remotely monitoring as well, sending just the sync timecode to the other studio via internet or phone line, is it possible to remotely operate a protools machine as well, like using Teamviewer or Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps Source-connect would help.

http://source-elements.com/

Answer (score 1):

They could have been using ISDN: transmitting Timecode and locking the 2 systems.  We do it all the time for ADR when clients are in LA and talent is in NYC.  You send TC on channel 1 of the ISDN signal, the receiving system chases to that, then you send the ADR audio via channel 2 and everything is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Aura Chef not sure this can help you but here something i used once before.

http://jackaudio.org or http://www.jackosx.com

http://netjack.sourceforge.net

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/openmixer/manual/using_netjack/netjack-under-osx

There is also a max/msp object you can read about it here  [here](http://www.nullmedium.de/dev/netsend~/), maybe max 6 has it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

@Aural Chef, do you know where you saw that video of George Lucas? I'm looking for teaching materials.